# Concflicting Sublime text 2 packages/plugins/snippets

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext

Have you ever experienced conflicts/bugs after installing one new package/plugin or snippets on Sublime Text 2 (i.e. conflicting shortcuts)?

Note to who down voted the question: it is your right to think it is a question that shouldn't be asked.

But, if like me, you have spend a great deal of time trying to find why the plugin you just have properly installed isn't working the way it should then you might reasonably be interested in finding some ressources listing known plugin conflicts.

Comment: Do you have an example of this? Otherwise, the answer to your question is 'No'

Comment: I don't have any example of this. Due to the increasing number of ST2 plugins, I thought plugin developers didn't/couldn't verify if their plugin would create a conflict. That's why I am asking this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is certainly possible, and honestly quite likely that plugins will conflict. Though I can't give a specific example where having 2 plugins installed causes one to break or have unexpected behavior (perhaps some of the autocomplete plugins cause this), conflicting shortcuts are certainly possible. There are only a finite amount of (comfortable) key combinations, so some are bound to conflict.

If you see some unexpected behavior (with regards to key bindings) after installing a plugin, might I suggest running the [FindKeyConflicts](https://github.com/skuroda/FindKeyConflicts) (note this plugin is developed by me) plugin. It should display any key conflicts that occur between packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. New to Sublime Text. I just wanted to help anyone not to waste their precious time.